# Background image not appearing error on github

Tags: html, css

The code works the way I intended it to, but I have encountered an unknow issue.

Github repo website link :https://rudratheboy.github.io/OrbitExplorer/home.html
Github repo link :https://github.com/RudraTheBoy/OrbitExplorer

I was doing this frontend mentor challenge and for an unknow reason the background image won't show up, the image path entered by me is also right.

I want the background image to appear.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your URL to `../assets/home/home-desktop.jpg`.

When you simply use `/assets/home/home-desktop.jpg`, it calls the resources in this path

> https://rudratheboy.github.io/OrbitExplorer/styles/assets/home/home-desktop.jpg

whereas the styles directory doesn't contains the assets, hence it return 404 and BG img is not appearing.

Your exact path for the resource is https://rudratheboy.github.io/OrbitExplorer/assets/home/home-desktop.jpg

Use this instead:

```css
.homeBackground {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("../assets/home/home-desktop.jpg") center center/cover;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="homeBackground"></div>
```

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: Hey!
Thank you very much for your help, the background image now appears.